# Algebraizable image of a morphism of Galois cohomology stacks

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, algebraic-stacks, galois-cohomology, rigid-analytic-geometry

Assume I have a surjective morphism of algebraic group schemes over $\mathbb{Q}_p$, $\mathcal{G}\longrightarrow S$, equipped with a section, and assume both of these group schemes are equipped with an action of the absolute Galois group of the rationals, denoted $G$.

Consider the induced morphism of Galois cohomology stacks:
$H^1(G, \mathcal{G})\longrightarrow H^1(G, S)$, these stacks are fibred above the category of rigid analytic spaces over $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Assume the stack $H^1(G, S)$ is representable and algebraizable, that is, there exists a scheme, say affine, $\text{Spec}R$, such that $H^1(G, S)$ is representable by its rigid analytification.

Is it true that the essential image of the morphism of stacks is algebraizable? That is, that there exists an algebraizable substack of $H^1(G,S)$ for which the fibre of the morphism of stacks as above is non empty above every point of the substack?

What if I also know that $H^1(G, \mathcal{G})$ is a vector bundle (not necessarily of constant rank) over $H^1(G, S)$?